# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory

Tags: .net, docker, oauth-2.0, google-api

We have a website with a .Net backend and Angular front end. We have built the image in Visual Studio and run the image on Docker Desktop. When we run the image, it exits with an error message as follows. It seems as if there is an issue finding the token.json file even when we try with a relative path. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=833331136290-k38j5u9ougoe518th2i92hdpfpcpl8h2.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A42299%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar" for authorization. See inner exception for details.)

 ---> System.NotSupportedException: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=833331136290-k38j5u9ougoe518th2i92hdpfpcpl8h2.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A42299%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar" for authorization. See inner exception for details.

 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory

   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)

   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()

   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName, String arguments)

   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.OpenBrowser(String url)

   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.ReceiveCodeAsync(AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl url, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.ReceiveCodeAsync(AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl url, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)

   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.AuthorizeAsync(String userId, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)

   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Initializer initializer, IEnumerable`1 scopes, String user, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IDataStore dataStore, ICodeReceiver codeReceiver)

   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(ClientSecrets clientSecrets, IEnumerable`1 scopes, String user, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IDataStore dataStore, ICodeReceiver codeReceiver)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)

   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()

   at TheMoonshineCafe.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/Program.cs:line 42
```

**Program.cs**

**Line 42: string credPath = "token.json";**

```
using (var stream =
                new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)
                    ).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }
```

Comment: Why do you suspect the issue is with the token.json file? Based on the callstack, the real issue seems to be that it's trying to launch a browser in a container requiring user interaction. I'm not familiar with Google's APIs but it seems like the approach to be taken here is to use an auth flow that doesn't require user interaction.

Comment: What was making me think this is an issue with the token.json was these two lines :

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory

at TheMoonshineCafe.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/Program.cs:line 42


However, that being said I was not really sure so I am looking into a different approach now that doesn't require user interaction.